# Calling an event handler manually

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an event handler method that's called directly as a standard method. That is, it's not only called when my event occurs but also just as a private method.

```
UtilStk.StkRoot.OnStkObjectAdded += new 
    IAgStkObjectRootEvents_OnStkObjectAddedEventHandler(TallyScenarioObjects);

private void TallyScenarioObjects(object sender)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it suitable to pass a null argument when calling this handler directly?

```
TallyScenarioObjects(null);
```

Comment: as long as your event handler handles the null value

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684513/how-to-trigger-a-timer-tick-programatically/4684566#4684566 - directly calling event handlers like this is a code smell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just encapsulate the common logic into another method that can be called from your event handler:

```
UtilStk.StkRoot.OnStkObjectAdded += new IAgStkObjectRootEvents_OnStkObjectAddedEventHandler(TallyScenarioObjects);

private void TallyScenarioObjects(object sender)
{
    DoStuff();
}

private void DoStuff() { ... }

private void AnotherMethod()
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

That said, your handler *is* a method, there's nothing special about it, so you could always dummy up arguments and call it directly.  I wouldn't go that route though.

Answer (score 7):

Yes that would work, but it would be better practice to have a 2nd method that could be called directly or from the event handler:

```
UtilStk.StkRoot.OnStkObjectAdded += new IAgStkObjectRootEvents_OnStkObjectAddedEventHandler(TallyScenarioObjects);

private void TallyScenarioObjects(object sender)
{
     DoTally(....);
}

private void DoTally(....)
{
}
```

If nothing else you won't confuse other developers who won't be expecting to see an event handler called that way.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the rest. Have your event call a method. Then you can invoke that method from wherever you'd like.

```
UtilStk.StkRoot.OnStkObjectAdded += new IAgStkObjectRootEvents_OnStkObjectAddedEventHandler(TallyScenarioObjects);

private void TallyScenarioObjects(object sender)
{
    MyMethod();
}

private  void MyMethod()
{
    //Code here.
}
```