# Delay display message by some time in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have a label, all what I want is, to display label as "name1" then wait for 5 seconds and then change it to "name2". This is how I did that

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "name1";
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
   Label1.Text = "name2";
}
```

What it does is it wait's for 5 seconds in total and then display "name2". "name1" is not displaying as I wished. I tried these links,

[How do I get my C# program to sleep for 50 msec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec)

[How to trigger a timer tick programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684513/how-to-trigger-a-timer-tick-programmatically)

Did not help. This [Using the ASP.NET Timer Control with Multiple UpdatePanel Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx) seems to work but this is keep on refreshing the page. I don't want this to happen, it should display name1 then wait for 5 seconds, display name2 and then stop.

Comment: If you are using server side code, the page will always refresh. You need to use client-side js to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using only what is provided, it should run once, so once the tick is complete we disable the timer.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
    Label1.Text = "name1";
    Timer1.Interval = 2000;
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "name2";
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The change you have mentioned must be on the client side, use javascript setTimer method and update the label to whatever text you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer control in your page under UpdatePanel for Async functionality **(for help on AJAX in ASP.net below are the links provided)**,
and then under its event use this logic for label name change:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
    Timer1.Interval = 5000;
 }

 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(Label1.Text == "name2")
    {
        Label1.Text = "name1";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "name2";
    }
 }
```

for more help on this you can check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/359958/how-to-use-timer-in-asp-net) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx)

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking for, can you make the timer stop once it's change to name2.

Comment: Yes you can do it just disable the timer as you have enabled it in page load.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle this the way you have in ASP.NET since you will always get the end result from the form_load event. You will have to use [JavaScript timing events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to handle this at the client side.

```
      <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('#label').val('label1');
                 setTimeout(SetLabel2, 5000); //wait for 5 seconds before setting the label. NOTE: This will keep on repeating until you clear the timeout
                });

                function SetLabel2(){
                  var l = $('#label).val();
                  if(l == 'label2)
                  {
                     window.clearTimeOut(); //So that this does not repeat
                  }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other contributors, you should use client code to obtain that kind of behavior. In your code sample, the `Page_Load` function simply takes 5 seconds to execute, and when all the processing on the server is done, the resulting HTML is finally sent to the browser... and you see "name2".

Here is a jQuery version of the client code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Label1').html("name1");
    setTimeout(function () { $('#Label1').html("name2"); }, 5000);
})
```

and here is a pure Javascript version:

```
var lbl1 = document.getElementById('Label1');
lbl1.innerHTML = "name1";
setTimeout(function () { lbl1.innerHTML = "name2" }, 5000);
```

If the ID of the Label is mangled by ASP.NET, you can use `<%= Label1.ClientID %>` instead of `Label1` in the client code.